# Django-celery project, how to handle results from result-backend?

Tags: django, celery

1) I am currently working on a web application that exposes a REST api and uses Django and Celery to handle request and solve them. For a request in order to get solved, there have to be submitted a set of celery tasks to an amqp queue, so that they get executed on workers (situated on other machines). Each task is very CPU intensive and takes very long (hours) to finish.

I have configured Celery to use also amqp as results-backend, and I am using RabbitMQ as Celery's broker.

Each task returns a result that needs to be stored afterwards in a DB, but not by the workers directly. Only the "central node" - the machine running django-celery and publishing tasks in the RabbitMQ queue - has access to this storage DB, so the results from the workers have to return somehow on this machine.

The question is how can I process the results of the tasks execution afterwards? So after a worker finishes, the result from it gets stored in the configured results-backend (amqp), but now I don't know what would be the best way to get the results from there and process them.

All I could find in the documentation is that you can either check on the results's status from time to time with:

```
result.state
```

which means that basically I need a dedicated piece of code that runs periodically this command, and therefore keeps busy a whole thread/process only with this, or to block everything with:

```
result.get()
```

until a task finishes, which is not what I wish.

The only solution I can think of is to have on the "central node" an extra thread that runs periodically a function that basically checks on the async_results returned by each task at its submission, and to take action if the task has a finished status.

Does anyone have any other suggestion?

Also, since the backend-results' processing takes place on the "central node", what I aim is to minimize the impact of this operation on this machine.

What would be the best way to do that?

2) **How do people usually solve the problem of dealing with the results returned from the workers and put in the backend-results?** (assuming that a backend-results has been configured)

Comment: A celery task consumer on the 'central node'.  The objective of this consumer is to save the data in the database. It works only when data is found in it's jobqueue hence its not periodic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but take into account each task has a task id. If tasks are being sent by users you can store the ids and then check for the results using json as follows:

```
#urls.py 
from djcelery.views import is_task_successful

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'(?P<task_id>[\w\d\-\.]+)/done/?$', is_task_successful,
        name='celery-is_task_successful'),
    )
```

Other related concept is that of [signals](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) each finished task emits a signal. A finnished task will emit a task_success signal. More can be found on [real time proc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing).

Comment: Yes, and the problem was that I need an event consumer, in order to catch the signals or something to check from time to time the status of the task...and this is independent of the part which submits jobs, because I wouldn't want to block the job submitting process with the looping over the task ids...The question is how do people usually do that?

Comment: Ok, I think I found my answer in the link you sent me regarding real time proc. Thanks!